# Knapsack Question, greedy method doesn't work?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I was doing the knapsack question: given n kinds of items, each item has infinite numbers to choose from. The volume of the ith item is A[i], and the value of the ith item is V[i]. Given a volume constraint of m, what is the largest value of items that can be contained under m?

Here is my code:

```
    def backPackIII(self, A, V, m):
        # write your code here
        dp = [0] * (m + 1)

        for i in range(len(A)):
            for j in range(m, 0, -1):
                max_num = j // A[i]
                max_val = max_num *  V[i] 
                
                dp[j] = max(dp[j], dp[j - A[i] * max_num] + max_val)
                
        return dp[-1]
```

I am not entirely sure why it doesn't work, or why is it different from the correct answer:

```
class Solution:

    def backPackIII(self, A, V, m):
        n = len(A)
        dp = [0] * (m + 1)
        
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(A[i], m + 1):
                dp[j] = max(dp[j], dp[j - A[i]] + V[i])
        
        return dp[m]
```

I thought in both functions, you are adding the maximum number of new items you can.

Comment: It will be helpful to include sample input and output, and clarify what do you mean "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

This problem is called Unbounded Knapsack:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

You can define dp[i] as the maximum value of things that have a total weight less than or equal to i.

So **dp[i] = max{dp[i], dp[i-A[j]]+V[j]}** when **i>=A[j]** and **j in range 1 to i**

And the answer will be **dp[m]**